# spring 3.1 how to use both AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext and XmlWebApplicationContext?

Tags: spring

I use AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext (instead of the default XmlWebApplicationContext) to set up the spring java based context.
However, I still have legacy code that requires some sprint xml based context.

Is it possible to use both AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext and XmlWebApplicationContext at the same time?

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        com.example.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration
        ...
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:test.xml
        ...
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if you can use both together, but what you can do, is only use `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext`

and on `PropertiesConfiguration` Spring Configuration class add the following annotation

`@ImportResource({"classpath:test.xml"})`